# Puppet: how to share a common resource / variable in modules

Tags: puppet

I am trying to use puppet to bootstrap a new VPS. I am going to be running multiple sites, and, at the moment I am planning on running them in separate user accounts. I want to have a common authorized key for all of these users. I am using puppet 4.10.

The issue I'm having is that I want to add my `ssh key` into the authorized_keys for all of these users, but I can't seem to work out how to have a common resource. I've tried adding it in a class and then including that, but it's a duplicate. I tried passing in a variable to the class, but again, duplicate.

Basically I have a module like this

```
class wibble_somesite {
  user { 'someuser':
    ensure         => 'present',
    managehome     => true,
    purge_ssh_keys => true,
    home => '/home/someuser',
    shell          =>  '/bin/bash'
  }

  ssh_authorized_key { 'patrickmacbookair':
    ensure => present,
    user   => 'someuser',
    type   => 'ssh-rsa',
    key    => 'some_shared_key'
  }
}
```

which I then include in my `manifests/site.pp`. However, I want to have multiples of these `class wibble_someothersite` and I want to centrally manage the `some_shared_key` inside the `ssh_authorized_key` stanza.

Any help would be appreciated. I have tried following the docs but I just haven't got anywhere.

I could just duplicate all the `ssh_authorized_key` calls, but that's obviously horrible.

Comment: Your description of the problem from a Puppet perspective given a route you have already decided upon is making it unclear what you are trying to achieve. Could you describe what you are trying to achieve from a Puppet-agnostic perspective? Then we can describe how to achieve that with Puppet best practices.

Comment: Hi Matt, sorry for the slow response. I am trying to create users and at the same time populate their `.ssh/authorized_keys` with a shared common key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have multiple instances of a class. However, you can with defined types.

Your example can be :

```
define wibble_somesite () {
  user { $title:
    ensure         => 'present',
    managehome     => true,
    purge_ssh_keys => true,
    home           => "/home/${title}",
    shell          =>  '/bin/bash'
  }

  ssh_authorized_key { "${title}_patrickmacbookair":
    ensure => present,
    user   => $title,
    type   => 'ssh-rsa',
    key    => 'some_shared_key'
  }
}
```

And you can use it like this :

```
wibble_somesite{'patrick':}
wibble_somesite{'bob':}
```

It will create users 'patrick' and 'bob', and allow the shared key to connect.

Is this what you are are looking for ?

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for thanks! I had tried with a define but I hadn't got the syntax correct, I'll have to read it again. I'm still a bit confused as to how the title gets in there, it not being a named param. Anyway, thanks very much - it's working perfectly!

Comment: Every puppet resource have a title. You usually pass it as the first argument. When you write `wibble_somesite{'patrick':}`, you create a resource wibble_somesite, with the title patrick. See https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/lang_defined_types.html#title-and-namehttps://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/lang_defined_types.html#title-and-name